# Python Pandas : Set column values as number of occurrences of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have problems with a for loop on two columns of my dataframe.
With this for loop I want to add a new column as I show you in this example:

I start with this dataframe:

```
     person       store_id
0    Rose         24256
1    Tim          24257
2    Tim          27896
3    Tim          29547
4    Jack         24258
5    Jack         27897
```

and the new column I would like to add should look like this.
In words I want to add a column showing a sort of enumeration of the stores visited by each person.

```
     person       store_id      enum
0    Rose         24256         1
1    Tim          24257         1
2    Tim          27896         2
3    Tim          29547         3
4    Jack         24258         1
5    Jack         27897         2
```

This is the code I tried, but I do not get what I want.

```
for x in df['person']:
    i = 1
    for x in df['store_id']:
        df['enum'] = i
        i = i + 1
```

I have also tried as follows, getting again a wrong result:

```
for x,y in zip(df['person'], df['store_id']):
    i = 1
    df['enum'] = i
    i = i + 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: In the first case I get for all the rows 6 as value.
In the second one 1 also for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to iterate over multiple columns; iterate with `iterrows` and use a dictionary to track visited store id position "enum", then you set the enum column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"person":[ 'Rose', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Jack', 'Jack' ],
                    "store_id": [1580407549, 1580557630, 1580571344, 1580647900, 1580755371, 1580911127]})

store_index = {}
enums = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sid = row['person']
    if sid not in store_index:
        store_index[sid] = 0
    store_index[sid] += 1
    enums.append(store_index[sid])
df['enum'] = enums
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  person    store_id  enum
0   Rose  1580407549     1
1    Tim  1580557630     1
2    Tim  1580571344     2
3    Tim  1580647900     3
4   Jack  1580755371     1
5   Jack  1580911127     2
```

Comment: I just have another question. I have tried to change some input data. The new data for store_id are longer numbers. Example: ```store_id': [1580407549, 1580557630, 1580571344, 1580647900, 1580755371, 1580911127]```. In this case the code does not work anymore and I get for the enum column values from 1 to 6. Could you explain me why?

Comment: These are all different `store_id`s so their enum value is diffrent

Comment: I think your code makes something different and not what I really meant. 
Now I have understood, why it does not work for the new data.

Comment: In the example you gave the `enum` corresponds to a unique value for each store_id according to it's position. What do you expect otherwise?

Comment: What I would like it is not an ID for each store, just counting the stores visited by each person. If the IDs are the same for more than one person it does not matter. 
Tim has visited 3 stores and I would like to have 1, 2, 3 as values. For Jack 1,2 not depending on the values of the store IDs.
I hope, now you can understand what I mean.. sorry, my fault in not explaing well!

Comment: Wow, that's much different from the example, however, updated :)
It works!